# How to test a script that relies on selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest, python-unittest

I've reached that point in my Python learning where I've written a script that relies in part on using Selenium to scrape a dynamically created webpage (for which Requests and BeautifulSoup are unrelevant).

**How, however, am I supposed to test these parts of my script?**

Is there a particular library for this? Do I have to develop a fake website (!) ? Or does the fact that the script works make it unnecessary to test it?

*PS: I understand that Selenium was initially created for development purposes and not for **webscraping**.*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/) and [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) along with the Jasmine Reports. The fact that your script works should be a testimony for the time being but for full-blown test reporting, you got to use the aforesaid tools.

Moreover, why not feed the page source derived from `Selenium` into `BeautifulSoup` and let it take care of the scraping part. Undermining `BeautifulSoup` and `Requests` for their capabilities is hard to stomach.

Comment: TestNG is for Java, not Python.  OP, take a look at unittest or pytest if you want to add some testing capabilities on top of your selenium

Comment: @CodeWalker: I edited my post in order to reflect the fact that the web pagecontent  I'm scraping is dynamically created as scrolled and its content can't be fed to Requests and BeautifulSoup, which capabilities are otherwise much appreciated. Thus the fact that I rely on Selenium.

Comment: @JD2775: Indeed, TestNG doesn't seem to help here. Could you elaborate on how unittest or pytest can be used in my situation?

Comment: @CygnusX you could just use them to add a test framework around your selenium methods.  For example, if you are expecting a particular Selenium action to return X, you could write a test against that and use the unittest Assert methods to ensure that X is returned. It is all about expected outcome vs actual outcome.  Unittest is built into Python, Pytest is another test framework you could choose instead

Comment: @JD2775: Thanks for your indications. I understand the process of unittesting, testing, etc. and I've become quite familiar with pytest, in particular. Here, the problem is that Selenium returns nothing, my script uses it to dynamically click on buttons, log on pages, scroll down, until I save some data. Is this whole behavior something that I should test and how so without doing it against the real site (in which case, what's the point?) ?

Comment: So you are saving some data at the end of the script?  That seems to me like it is returning "something".  Couldn't you validate that the data is what you expected it to be?  Or is it a case of you really don't know what the data will be until you get it?  In that case I think the only real thing you can test is that SOME data is returned.  Or, if you are returning data to an Excel or CSV or something similar, there is a lot you can do with Pandas to analyze the data is what you expect it to be.  You dont necessarily need a testing framework for that

Comment: Or, if you aren't concerned with the end data and testing that it is correct, you could just add assertions that web elements are present when you click them? Or send keys?  Then again, if they weren't present your script would fail anyway.

Comment: @JD2775 Ok, thanks. Your comments make me to think that what I could test is that the webpages that lead to the desired data remain unchanged (expected web elements, tags, ids, etc. are still there), so that when the time comes, my script will run as it should. Because, then again, if testing means running my script against the real webpages, then there's no real test here. I suppose that's an edge case where it is acceptable to have code coverage by tests below 100%.